# Android Load html pages stored in assets folder in a webview

Tags: android, webview

My app have to show 5 HTML pages stored in assets folder, how to show them in a single webview.

Comment: What do you mean by showing five pages in a single web view?

As for how to actually load a page from the assets folder, see my answer below.

Comment: @Stefan Hållén see my accepted answer to know what I mean.

Comment: What is the reason for down voting??????

Comment: That was a fairly badly phrased question then. Your issue obviously didn't even have to do with Android nor WebView, you wanted to know how to make links between pages in HTML.

Comment: @Stefan Hållén ok good u took it that way, then enjoy.............

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I found this, and it is dedicated to Mr.Stefan Hållén(for understanding my question)**

`

```
private WebView mWebView = null;    
    private TextView selectedText = null;   
    private long timeLeft;
    private int pageIndex;
    private String pagePath;    
    private String[] pageList;  
    private AssetManager assMan =null;    
    private String path="Courses/Section01";  
    private int SelectedRow;
       @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
            
            setContentView(R.layout.course);

            mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
            
            assMan= this.getAssets();
            
             try {
                pageList = aMan.list(path);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
             pageIndex=0;
             
             System.out.println(pageList[0]);
             
             System.out.println(pageList.length);
             
             pagePath=pageList[pageIndex];
            
            loadWebView(pagePath);

            Button nextView = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nxt); 
            
                       nextView.setOnClickListener(NextClick);

                   
        Button   previousView = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pre);  
                       previousView.setOnClickListener(PreviousClick);
       }
       
       View.OnClickListener PreviousClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
            
            public void onClick(View v) {
                GoPrevious();
                
            }
        };
         View.OnClickListener NextClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
                
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    GoNextNews();
                    
                }
            };
       private void loadWebView(String s){
        
            //mWebView.loadUrl(s);
            
            mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/htmlFilesFolder/"+s);
            
        }


        private void GoNextNews() {
            
            int TotalRows = pageList.length;
            
            if ((SelectedRow + 1) < TotalRows) 
            {
                SelectedRow = SelectedRow + 1;
                
                String s=pageList[SelectedRow];
                
                loadWebView(s);
                }
        } 

        private void GoPrevious() {
            
            if (SelectedRow > 0) 
            {
                SelectedRow = SelectedRow - 1;
                
                String s=pageList[SelectedRow];
                
                loadWebView(s);
                
            }
        } 
}`
```

Answer (score 11):

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.YourWebView);
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/your.html");
```

Comment: I know how to load HTML page, my question is how to show "5 HTML pages" in a "single" web view.

Answer (score 3):

```
<WebView
   android:id="@+id/testWebView"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">     
 </WebView>
```

then create html page with navigation lake this:

```
    <body>

<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="page1.html" title="page 1">Page 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="page2.html" title="page 2">Page 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="page3.html" title="page 3">Page 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="page4.html" title="page 4">Page 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="page5.html" title="page 5">Page 5</a></li>
</ul>


<h1> page 1</h1>
</body>
```

then load first page:

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.testWebView); 
 webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/page1.html");
```

and so you get a html page with navigation to other pages

Answer (score 1):

You are actually talking about SPA(Single Page Application) if i am not wrong. You should Take a look at Angularjs which is a framework that has a proparty routeProvider.You can easily load  your html pages which are actually partials in your main html page. Just give some time on the billow link...oh...it will work for android and ios too if you add phonegap on your project.

http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07

http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial

happy to help...

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to first copy the html files from Assets to Internal Directory (getFilesDir()). And then perform

webView.loadUrl("file://"+getFilesDir()+"/firstPage.html");

because from Assets directly, it fails for some devices.